# An invalid floating point operation occurred POWER SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am have a problem with the code, when I run I get

`An invalid floating point operation occurred`

My code is the following:

```
select POWER( ISNULL(value1,0) / NULLIF(value2,0) , 12 / CONVERT(numeric(6,2),value3))
```

where value1(data type: money), value2(data type: money), value3(data type: int) are columns in my database.

I get that error when value1 = Null, value2 = 164083520.00 and value3 = 177

The weird is that if I replace with these numbers I get right result, but not while running this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried those exact values and data types and didn't get an error

Comment: This doesn't give an error: DECLARE @t table(value1 money, value2 money, value3 int)
INSERT @t
values( Null, 164083520.00, 177)


SELECT POWER( ISNULL(value1,0) / NULLIF(value2,0) , 12 / CONVERT(numeric(6,2),value3))
FROM @t

Comment: Bear in mind that even if you have a `WHERE` clause, such that you *think* it's only evaluating this expression on those particular values, it's actually not - it may well be trying to evaluate this expression on other rows in the table...

Answer (score 0):

Executing the following script I'm not getting any errors on SQL Server 2012. AFAICT you won't get any on other versions either. You must be having a calculation somewhere else that results in an invalid floating point operation.

```
DECLARE @values TABLE(value1 MONEY,value2 MONEY,value3 INT);
INSERT INTO @values(value1,value2,value3)VALUES(NULL,164083520.00,177);

SELECT
    result=POWER(ISNULL(value1,0)/NULLIF(value2,0), 12.0/CONVERT(numeric(6,2),value3))
FROM
    @values;
```

Result

```
0.00
```